# Multiple Set handlers in a property

Tags: vb.net, properties

I remember coming across some way to declare multiple Set handlers in a property but now I can't figure out how it's done.  It's useful in that one can assign different data types and the Set handler does the conversion, but I get the error

> 'Set' is already declared

thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot have multiple Set statements for a class property.  A property cannot be overridden.

You can use a setter functions (this is mostly a paradigm in Java) and overload that if you need to.  Then I would also suggest making the property readonly.

One other option is to have the property be defined as an Object and in the set check the `TypeOf` of the value being used to set the property and do whatever business logic you want.  The only problem with this approach is that then your property doesn't have type checking.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right.  pity that.  it must be for the same reason that .net doesn't allow overloading the assignment operator.  sigh...

Answer (score 2):

## It's not possible

It would be nice to be able to write both

```
sQuantity = "1234"
```

and

```
sQuantity = 1234
```

with two setter functions, but trying to write even one setter function with the wrong parameter type seems doomed to failure:-

```
error BC31064: 'Set' parameter must have the same type as the containing property.
```

If Visual Basic doesn't allow conversion between setter parameter type and property type then there is no way it would be possible to have two setter functions. If setter functions are forced to have the same type as the property, then it could not know which to run if there were more than one!

So I'd argue '**not only does it not seem possible, but it is actually not possible**!'

### There is a workaround

What you can do however, is have two properties of different types changing the same underlying variable, so that you can write

```
sQuantityFromString = "1234"
```

and

```
sQuantityFromInt = 1234
```

using

```
Public Shared WriteOnly Property sQuantityFromInt () As Integer
```

with a setter function that takes an integer as a parameter and with both properties setter functions modifying the same underlying string member variable.

```
Private Shared m_sQuantity As String = Nothing
```